# One to Many Relationship MongoDb Using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a relationship between a User and Address. User can have multiple Address. Here is my schema:

**userSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const Address = require('./addressSchema')


let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name :String,
  age : Number,
  cohort :String,
  addresses : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Address'}]
})


let User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

**addressSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let addressSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  city : String,
  state :String
})

let Address = mongoose.model('Address',addressSchema)
module.exports = Address
```

**Adding New User and Address (app.js)**

```
let user = new User({name : 'Mary', age : 36, cohort : 2019})
let address = new Address({ city : 'Houston', state : 'TX'})

user.addresses.push(address)


user.save(function(error,newUser){
  console.log(newUser)
})
```

**Fetching the users and their addresses**
// fetch all users

```
User.find(function(error,users){

  users.forEach((user) => {
    console.log('addresses')
    user.addresses.forEach((address) => {
      console.log(address.city) // prints undefined
    }) 
  })

})
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish: storing the addresses as embedded documents in user *OR* storing references to address documents in user. The example code above has blended both approaches which, as you have noticed, does not work.

---

### Embedded:

Combine the schemas:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const addressSchema = Schema({
    city : String,
    state :String
})

const userSchema = Schema({
  name :String,
  age : Number,
  cohort :String,
  addresses : [addressSchema]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

And the rest of the code can remain the same.

---

### References:

The existing schema and model declarations remain the same.

Then when the data is stored, the address also needs to be stored:

```
const user = new User({name : 'Mary', age : 36, cohort : 2019})
const address = new Address({ city : 'Houston', state : 'TX'})

user.addresses.push(address)

Promise.all([
  user.save(),
  address.save()
]).then(([newUser, newAddress]) => {
  console.log({newUser, newAddress});
});
```

And finally when fetching the document, if the address is meant to be included then it needs to be populated:

```
User.find().populate('addresses').exec().then((users) => {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    user.addresses.forEach((address) => {
      console.log({user, address});
    });
  });
});
```